# How do I work out the odds of choosing five matching pairs from a selection of ten items?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Here's the example.

I have 10 boxes consisting of 5 matching pairs of items (red gloves, red socks, blue socks, gold earrings, diamond earrings).

What are the odds of choosing two boxes with the same contents to complete a pair at each stage of the game?

Assuming the first two boxes are opened and they are matching red gloves, the odds would be...? Then the second two boxes are opened and they are matching diamond earrings, the odds are then...?

Presumably as each pair is opened and they match, the odds of matching the next two boxes become more likely as the variables decrease, but the odds that I managed to match them all in succession get less likely?

Comment: Is there exactly one item in each box?

Comment: At stage #1, the probability is $\frac{5}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{1}{9}$. At stage #2, the probability is $\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{\binom{8}{2}}+\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{\binom{8}{2}}=\frac{1}{9}$ (which is $1$ ninth, I don't know why the browser doesn't parse this LaTex properly).

Comment: @barak manos: I would have thought the probability at the second stage, given success at the first stage, would be $\frac17$

Comment: That makes sense. To answer the first question, yes the boxes contain 1 item each - i.e. there is one red glove in one box and the other in a different box. I understand that the first two boxes matching is 1/9 (can't figure out how to write the fractions) and therefore it is 1/7, 1/5, 1/3 and 1/1 in the following rounds. The bit i'm struggling with is what the odds are of five matching pairs occurring in a row without the previous rounds revealing what they have... Is it 9x7x5x3?

Comment: @Henry: I calculated the probability of success at the second stage regardless of the result at the first stage (i.e., the sum of the probabilities in both cases - first stage success and first stage failure). To my understanding, the question OP asks about the probability of success at each stage independently.

Comment: @barak manos: You may be correct - I am now confused about the question.  If you do not know the results of any rounds, then the marginal probability for each round is constant - as you say $\frac19$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear. As two boxes are removed in each round, there are 8 boxes left after round 1, 6 after round 2, 4 after round 3 and so on. That would mean that the odds for each round would be 1/9, 1/7, 1/5, 1/3 and 1/1. Then follows the question regarding what the odds are that in each round a matching pair is found all the way through the game without any mismatches showing up? I think it would be 9 x 7 x 5 x 3 = 1/945 ...

Comment: @barakmanos To answer your LaTeX question, when you have a long line of text like that, the system inadvertently puts a space in between. Try finding a place before that to add a space.

Comment: @EdwardJiang: OK, got it. Thanks. I've never seen it happening in the answer text-box, so I guess it only applies for comments...? Anyway, it's too late to change that comment, but I'll use your advice next time... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't require conditional probability to solve this.

You have 10 items hidden in boxes, consisting of 5 paired items.

There is no bias on selecting boxes in each stage.

The **Total Space** consists of $\Box$ ways to pick any boxes 2 at a time.

The **Favored Space** consists of $\Box$ ways to pick pairs each time.

The probability is therefore: $$\frac{\Box}{\Box}$$